# Responsive Image and div content CSS and HTMl

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working on a responsive html page and I have this code to hide some content and sets a long image when view in mobile or when your web browser is minimized.

**CSS**

```
  @media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
     .mobile_only {
       width:600px !important;
       overflow:visible !important;
       float: none !important;
       }
   }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="mobile_only" style="width:0px; overflow:hidden;float:left">test</div>
<img src="longimage.png" title="hide me in mobile thanks"/>
```

Comment: Use `max-width` instead of `max-device-width`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use  `max-width` instead of `max-device-width` you can also remove your `inline style` from the `element` and write your it in `<style>`

```
.mobile_only{
  width:0px;
  overflow:hidden;
  float:left;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .mobile_only {
    width:600px !important;
    overflow:visible !important;
    float: none !important;
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uvmpde98/